# Android build fails when using dagger 2.18 with kotlin kapt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am attempting to include in my android project the dagger android processor version 2.18 with kotlin-kapt. I am also using the androidx package structure. I have added all the required dependencies but upon building my project I am getting the below error.

```
[kapt] An exception occurred: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at com.sun.tools.javac.util.List$2.next(List.java:432)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:302)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:254)
at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeys.mapKeyValue(AndroidMapKeys.java:75)
at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeys.lambda$annotationsAndFrameworkTypes$5(AndroidMapKeys.java:56)
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1321)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:419)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeys.annotationsAndFrameworkTypes(AndroidMapKeys.java:56)
at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeyValidator.annotations(AndroidMapKeyValidator.java:65)
at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.getSupportedAnnotationClasses(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:146)
at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.getSupportedAnnotationTypes(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:158)
at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.getSupportedAnnotationTypes(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:103)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.getSupportedAnnotationTypes(annotationProcessing.kt)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:505)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:597)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:690)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:55)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:27)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:213)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:178)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:95)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:105)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:375)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:366)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:120)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:441)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1020)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1062)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1019)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:440)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Apparently the build runs successfully when using dagger version 2.18. What could be the problem? Is this a known issue with dagger or the new android packaging structure or kotlin-kapt?

UPDATE

Below is my app gradle file with the dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ke.co.unirides.unirides"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}

ext {
    dagger_version = '2.18'
    room_version = '2.0.0'
    lifecycle_version = '2.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// Kotlin
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

// Android KTX
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'

// UI Frameworks
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

// Navigation
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"

// Dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"

// Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"

// Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// Paging
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.0.0"

// Testing
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Comment: Can we see the dependencies too?

Comment: To use `dagger` you can simply add these: ```kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"```

Comment: Simple workaround: switch back to 2.16.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue, check https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1245.
For now you need to roll back to 2.16

Answer (score 9):

Instead of rolling back you can now use latest dagger version (at this point is 2.21) but also **update Android Gradle Plugin** (aka build tools) **to 3.3.0+**

Answer (score 0):

Fixed & worked ok with fresh dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.35.1'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.23.2'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.35'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.35'
```